# Kendo UI - export Grid to PDF without pages chunks

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have [Kendo UI Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index) with paging chunks of 5 -

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  pdf: {
    allPages: true
  },
  pageable: true,
  dataSource: {
    type: "odata",
    pageSize: 5,
    data: [...]
  }
})
```

And an [export to PDF](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/drawing-dom) of this Grid -

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var progress = $.Deferred();
grid._drawPDF(progress)
```

[Here is its DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@urielz/AYenE)

Currently the export create the PDF with all the Grid content but with chunks of 5 ,

how could I export to the PDF with all the content without the chunks ?

(Note - I only want to change the export view not the view on the DOM )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It borrow pageSize property from grid. You need to change that to number of records which you would like to have on one page.

[Dojo exemple](http://dojo.telerik.com/afECe)

Comment: Great ! I set the `pageSize` to - `grid.dataSource.pageSize(/*length of all my entities*/)` and it works .